# it is possible to merge two profiles in quality sonarqube

Tags: sonarqube

I would like to know if you have a junction between the two profiles of quality, creating a single.

I have a project that uses the JEE technology, and it uses javascript, java and JSF.

Wanted to make a junction of quality profiles (Web + Javascript + Sonar way with Findbugs)

Is there any way to do this?

---

I'm using sonarqube 4.3 and sonar runner 2.4.

According for your reply

I have to call the sonar runner several times

first for  Sonar way in Web perfil

second for Sonar way in JavaScript perfis

third  for Sonar way with Findbugs in Java perfis

would give me an example?

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't have to do this and this is not the correct way to solve your problem anyway.

As of SonarQube 4.2 you can use the multilanguage feature and your files will be automatically  analyzed by the correct language plugin (detection is based on file extension).

If you are using a version prior to 4.2 you will have to run multiple analysis with the correct language set each time.